# Storing 3rd party OAuth2 tokens in Salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce-component

I am developing an app and this app is authenticated using OAuth2. Where do you I store the OAuth access and refresh tokens in Salesforce? Is Custom Setting the best approach ? Also, how do i store tokens of multiple users.

Answer (score 0):

Yes custom setting will be best option here.

```
Hierarchy__c CS = Hierarchy__c.getInstance(userinfo.getuserId());
System.Assert(CS.Accesstoken__c== '******');
```

You can create a [Hierarchical type custom setting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm) and based on user can create data there. Because query on custom setting does not count against SOQL governor limit so it will help you in limits as well.

Comment: What about using a list custom setting? Are there disadvantages to that?

Comment: @akcorp2003 there is no disadvantage but normally in this scenario we use Hierarchical CS because here you can create record for user basis and easily get them using the code I have posted.

Comment: So is this the only way or are there better ways ?

Comment: @Ranga I think in your use case its best way but not the only way. You can still use list CS or Object.